# How to display object key of only the entries that have a designated value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, discord.js

So I have a `discord.js` object that is a list of all the permissions (true or false) that a member has. I am trying to loop through these entries and 'extract' only the ones that have the value of `true`. I have gotten so far as to be able to pick out a singular entry based on its value, but it only returns one entry, as I am not looping over it yet.

I have tried inserting the function in to a for/in loop. But I believe I did it incorrectly, as it did not filter the entries based on their values.

This is the code I currently have that will display the singular entry.

```js
let memPerms = message.member.permissions.serialize(true)
    function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
        return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
    }
    message.channel.send(getKeyByValue(memPerms, true))
```

Short term, I want to be able to `console.log` the output where it displays all of the entries that are true inside the object. Long term, I will have those entries sent to the member inside of discord. But I only need help getting to my short term goal, as after that, it is well withing my abilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get *all* the keys, use `filter` not `find`:

```
return Object.keys(object).filter(key => object[key] === value);
```

Comment: Wow, never would have thought I would be so braindead to such a simple answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem whatsoever @Timesis, always glad to help.